# python Shorten the embedded try-except block

Tags: python, python-requests, try-except

I've been using `try-except` inside another `try-except`, when I try to open a url which may or may not lack an 'http://' header.

But the code looks messy. I'm wondering if python has some nicer ways to deal with such needs.  Actually I've read the 'with' keyword.. Which somehow, I feel, will make the code harder to read...

I've got links to open, but the links may have something missing. For example the url is like.  either xxx.com or http : / / xxx . com. And I have to test 
http:// and url, http:// plus www. plus url, url
to find the right one.

And if none works, I must record the reason why, and go on with the next link:

```
    for link in links:
        url = link
        if not url.startswith('http'):
            try:
                url1 = r'http://'+link
                res = requests.get(url)
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    url2 = r'http://www.'+link
                    res = requests.get(url)
                except Exception as err:
                    self.print_error(*[url1, modify(e.message)])
                    self.print_error(*[url2, modify(err.message)])
                    self.error_log(*[url1, modify(e.message)])
                    self.error_log(*[url2, modify(err.message)])

        else:
            try:
                res = request.get(url)
            except Exception as e:
                self.print_error(*[url, modify(e.message)])
                self.error_log(*[url, modify(e.message)])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First assemble a list of potential URLs in order of priority:

```
potential_urls = [link, 'http://' + link, 'http://www.' + link]
```

Also keep a list of errors you’ve encountered:

```
errors_encountered = []
```

Then go through the list, `break`ing if it works.

```
res = None
for url in potential_urls:
    try:
        res = requests.get(url)
    except Exception as err:
        errors_encountered.append(err)
    else:
        break
```

If none of the attempts work, we’ll leave `res` set to `None`, which we can detect and log as desired:

```
if res is None:
    for url, err in zip(potential_urls, errors_encountered):
        self.print_error(url, modify(err.message))
    for url, err in zip(potential_urls, errors_encountered):
        self.error_log(url, modify(err.message))
```

Otherwise, it succeeded, and you can use `res` as usual.

Comment: Wow,, yeah, python list is very easy to use. and the code is much cleaner now.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of setting `res = None` to check it, you can just use an `else:` clause on the `for` loop. (I'm not sure it's necessarily more readable, but I wanted to point it out; this is exactly what `for…else` is for, and so many people seem to forget about it.)

Comment: @abarnert: Oh, clever. I suppose that would work, but indeed, it’s not very readable. I had heard of that construct, but apparently I completely misunderstood how it worked: I thought that it would only execute the `else` if the iterable had no items; but no, rather, it always executes unless `break` is used. (Obviously, under that former interpretation, it wouldn’t be of use here.) Just because it’s not particularly well-known, I’m not going to include it, but I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @icktoofay: Under the former interpretation, it wouldn't be of much use very often at all. Anyway, it's a shame that it isn't particularly well known, but I don't blame you for not trying to solve that problem in the middle of an answer to a question with 1 upvote on SO. :) I just wanted to leave it in a comment.

Comment: @abarnert: I think it’d be quite useful if you were, for example, building HTML and you might want to show an “oops! no items!” if there’s no items or something, but then it’s easy enough to use an `if` there…

Comment: @icktoofay: You're right. _Usually_ in a for loop either you're accumulating something, and the fact that you ended up with an empty something is all you need, or you're doing pure side effects, and you don't need to know what was done after the fact… but "usually" isn't "always", and you're right, I can imagine cases where I'd want to know (as a yes/no, not a count or anything else) whether anything got done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one other possibility, which simply reduces the nesting by continuing through the loop on success.

```
for link in links:
    url = link
    if not url.startswith('http'):
        try:
            url1 = r'http://'+link
            res = requests.get(url)
            continue # we succeeded
        except Exception as e:
            pass

        try:
            url2 = r'http://www.'+link
            res = requests.get(url)
        except Exception as err:
            self.print_error(*[url1, modify(e.message)])
            self.print_error(*[url2, modify(err.message)])
            self.error_log(*[url1, modify(e.message)])
            self.error_log(*[url2, modify(err.message)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @icktoofay's answer, but working from the perspective that you probably only need to work if the link succeeded or not.

Define a function that does possible attempts and either returns a requests object, or after attempting all possibilities, raises an exception.

```
def try_get(link):
    for url in (link, 'http://' + link, 'http://www.' + link):
        try:
            return requests.get(url)
        except Exception:
            pass
    raise ValueError('no url was suitable', link)
```

Then loop over your urls, and either use `res` or do something suitable with the exception.

```
for url in list_of_urls:
    try:
        res = try_get(url)
    except ValueError as e:
        print e
```